# Biblatex is printing a 5 digit number when converting to pdf

Tags: biblatex, emacs, org-mode, zotero

I am using [Emacs Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/) to export to pdf. I get a five digit number printing out in the references like the 00005 below.

> Schneier, B., (2004, January), Secrets and *Lies: Digital Security in
>   a Networked World* (1 edition), 00005, New York: Wiley.

My .bib file looks like this. I think [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) is putting the numbers in all the **"note = "**.

```
    @book{schneier_secrets_2004,
    address = {New York},
    edition = {1 edition},
    title = {Secrets and {Lies}: {Digital} {Security} in a {Networked} {World}},
    isbn = {9780471253112},
    shorttitle = {Secrets and {Lies}},
    abstract = {Bestselling author Bruce Schneier offers his expert guidance on achieving security on a networkInternationally recognized computer security expert Bruce Schneier offers a practical, straightforward guide to achieving security throughout computer networks. Schneier uses his extensive field experience with his own clients to dispel the myths that often mislead IT managers as they try to build secure systems. This practical guide provides readers with a better understanding of why protecting information is harder in the digital world, what they need to know to protect digital information, how to assess business and corporate security needs, and much more.* Walks the reader through the real choices they have now for digital security and how to pick and choose the right one to meet their business needs* Explains what cryptography can and can't do in achieving digital security},
    language = {English},
    publisher = {Wiley},
    author = {Schneier, Bruce},
    month = jan,
    year = {2004},
    note = {00005}
}
```

So the cause of the problem is the note = {00005}. Oddly it doesn't happen with pandoc to .odt from the command line. Only with the .pdf export.

The relevant bit of my .org file.

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[british]{babel}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{csquotes}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,url=true, doi=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=3,language=british]{biblatex}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{/home/felixdz/Dropbox/bibliography/references}
```

How do I stop the five digit numbers from printing?

Comment: Is Zotero also responsible for `1 edition` (which is wrong) and the incorrect curly brackets in `title` and `shorttitle`?

Comment: You could stop the printing of all `note` fields but that would be unwise since the field is intended for necessary information which does not fit elsewhere. By far the best option is to stop Zotero producing entries which are wrong or to use an alternative method for managing your bibliography database.

Comment: The best solution is to get Zotero to not add things to the `note` field, which is a field that is meant to be printed by default (and not just by `biblatex`).  Second best option: if you are using `Biber` you can dynamically change your entry fields. Third best option: if you rely on BibTeX, then you can do `#+latex_header: \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}`.

Comment: Thanks for these replies. I think I will query the Zotero forums then report back. I also thought the "1 Edition" looked odd.

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide a bit more details for those coming to this later, not least because I think describing this as a Zotero problem is a bit misleading--Zotero is doing exactly what it should. It's a data-entry problem. 
Particular when importing from low-data-quality sources like Amazon, users need to clean up data after import. That's true not just when exporting to bibtex, but also in order to generate correct citations with Zotero's built-in functionality. Specifically:

1. Curly brackets: Zotero expects titles to be entered in [sentence case](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/sentence_casing). Because of that, any word starting with a capital letter is treated as a proper noun and thus enclosed in curly brackets to prevent bibtex from forcing lowercase.
2. The `note` field in bibtex is populated from the "Extra" field in Zotero, which serves a roughly similar purpose. The reason it contains 0005 in this case is almost certainly because the user installed a [3rd party add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-uS/firefox/addon/zotero-scholar-citations/) that does just that.
   (there's a bit of a philosophical issue here in that Zotero always includes as much data as possible for items, whereas many bibtex styles assume that all provided data should be cited -- that also explains the month given for a book citations, which is incorrect APA. From Zotero's perspective, I'd call this a bug in the apa.bst, but it's mainly a difference in approach. The same is true for the Extra/Note field: There is no such thing as a "Note" in an APA book citation, so even with an Extra field populated, Zotero wouldn't include this in an APA citation, but the apa.bst style does include it for `note`. So unless you're mixing Zotero-generated bibtex with that from other sources, I'd say that using `\clearfield` as suggested in comments above works just fine).
3. As noted above, just like in bibtex, the edition field should read "1" (or, likely, in this case just be empty) in Zotero.

Comment: Ad 2: This is incorrect.  BibTeX styles do not and cannot "assume that all provided data should be cited": only fields explicitly catered for in the `.bst` (traditional BibTeX) and `.bbx/.cbx` (biblatex) are used. You can add all kinds of 'custom' fields to an entry (e.g., a library call number field) without fear that they will be printed.  Zotero should *not* export to the `note` field unless it expects that information needs to be printed. (And as far as possible, your `.bib` should be style agnostic: so whether `apa.bst` should or should not print the `note` field is irrelevant, IMO).

Comment: Agreed, though, that problems that arise from relying on Zotero (which I stopped using for this very reason) are mostly the 'fault' of the data it is scooping.

Comment: well, Zotero maps "Extra" to ```note``` in its own citation styles, too, so I think the mapping makes a lot of sense and we're going to keep it. (There's also the problem that bibtex is also used for data exchange--awkward as that is--so we like to keep the records as comprehensive as possible).  You're correct on the other point, obviously .bsts need to explicitly define fields to be used, but I'll stick to the claim that they tend to be very inclusive in using fields regardless of item type/citation if they're in the `.bib` file, as per the month example I cite (which is incorrect APA style)

Comment: If it is meant to be printed, then keep it; otherwise, map it to a filed like `annote` or `ksahskhskd`, and it won't. As for the "inclusivity" problem, then it's a faulty implementation of the APA style.  (But you should use the `biblatex-apa` package, which requires Biber as the backend in place of BibTeX: it is, I think, a far more faithful implementation of APA's rather complex demands [which are based on the philosophy that you'd be typing everything 'by hand' to begin with].)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to me a Zotero problem rather than a Biblatex problem. I found through  the [Zotero Forums](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/48787/biblatex-is-printing-a-5-digit-number-when-converting-to-pdf-and-1-edition-instead-of-1st/#Comment_223387) that the five digit number is caused by a field in Zotero called "Extra" and the 1 Edition instead of 1st Edition are caused by the import from Amazon.

The workaround will be to manually remove the 'Extra' field in Zotero and correct the editions for the books. I'll also have to ensure these are correct when I add new entries.

Thanks for those who replied.